# Getting average value in JOIN query, Works in raw MySql but does not work in Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got this query written out in Laravel query builder, bu when i run it, it returns this error: **Call to a member function join() on float**

```
$avgYield= DairyCropYield::avg('moisture')
            ->join('dairy_crops','dairy_crops.id','=','dairy_crop_yields.dairy_crop_id')
            ->join('dairy_crop_varieties','dairy_crops.dairy_crop_variety_id','=','dairy_crop_varieties.id')
            ->where('dairy_crop_varieties.crop','=',$crop->crop)
            ->whereYear('harvested_at','=',Carbon::now()->year)
            ->get();
```

But when i write the same query in mySql it wroks as exptected:

```
SELECT AVG(moisture) FROM dairy_crop_yields AS yield JOIN dairy_crops AS crop ON crop.id = yield.dairy_crop_id JOIN dairy_crop_varieties AS variety ON variety.id = crop.dairy_crop_variety_id WHERE variety.crop = 'corn' AND YEAR(harvested_at) = 2015
```

Any thoughts / suggestions on what I am not doing right in Laravel query builder.
I do want to master and stick with Laravel's query builder.
Thanks.

Comment: try convert it `->toSql()` so its query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `avg` after the `get()`, the `avg` method works on a collection. So what you want is to `get()` all the result first then only call the `avg('moisture')` on the available results.

```
$avgYield= DairyCropYield::join('dairy_crops','dairy_crops.id','=','dairy_crop_yields.dairy_crop_id')
        ->join('dairy_crop_varieties','dairy_crops.dairy_crop_variety_id','=','dairy_crop_varieties.id')
        ->where('dairy_crop_varieties.crop','=',$crop->crop)
        ->whereYear('harvested_at','=',Carbon::now()->year)
        ->get()
        ->avg('moisture');
```

Alternately, you can also do something like this using `DB::raw`

```
$avgYield= DairyCropYield::select(DB::raw('AVG(moisture)'))
    ->join('dairy_crops','dairy_crops.id','=','dairy_crop_yields.dairy_crop_id')
    ->join('dairy_crop_varieties','dairy_crops.dairy_crop_variety_id','=','dairy_crop_varieties.id')
    ->where('dairy_crop_varieties.crop','=',$crop->crop)
    ->whereYear('harvested_at','=',Carbon::now()->year)
    ->get();
```